# Open a file selection window to top-most position from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

## Background

I came up with this solution to a question that I posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307442/in-jupyter-notebook-how-to-bring-tkinter-filedialog-window-to-the-top-of-all-win). It uses Tkinter to create a file select dialog window and raise it to the topmost position from jupyter notebook.

## Questions

1) Is there some kind of built in or canonical way to do this in jupyter notebook that I've missed in my searches?

2) Is there any redundancy?

```
from tkinter import*
# Create Tk root
root = Tk()
# Hide the main window
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)

from tkinter import filedialog
infiles = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)

%gui tk
```

Comment: Why do you want fewer lines? Readability and maintainability should trump lines of code.

Comment: @Mast agreed. I should rephrase that to say: is there any redundant code.